# Checking if a click happened "off" an object

Tags: game-maker

Having made the first game in Game Maker, Catch the Clown, I realised there was no way to win or lose.

Winning is easy enough, set a maximum score and a test that fires whenever a score increments, but losing has proved challenging. I had an idea; if the player attempts to click on the clown but misses he/she loses a life. I have tested every check, read the manual and looked through forums but I can't find a way to do this.

I also can't figure out where to put the event. I tried on the clown; tests like checking to if there would be a collision between where the click occurred and where the clown is... nothing works. I am at a complete loss so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question concerns the [order of events](http://wiki.yoyogames.com/index.php/Order_of_events) (when they are relatively called to one another). My answer takes advantage of the fact that mouse click events occur between Begin Step and End Step events. That means one solution would be the following:

1. Have an obj_controller (bad name and design practice, but fairly commonly done with GM) that has a `clicked` variable and a `hit` variable.
2. In obj_controller's Begin Step, set `hit` and `clicked` to false
3. In obj_controller's Global Mouse Left Pressed event (this would indicate there has been a hit somewheres on screen, possibly a misfire, possibly not), set the `clicked` variable to true
4. Have an object called obj_clown that is the target your user is trying to hit.
5. In obj_clown's Left Pressed event, increment score, tell obj_controller that there has been a verified hit by setting obj_controller's `hit` variable to true (this can be done using the following GML:

   ```
   ///Tell the obj_controller a hit was made
   with(obj_controller) {
       hit = true;
   }
   ```

   ), and destroy itself (so the clown is gone).
6. In obj_controller's End Step event, check if `clicked` is true and `hit` is false. This means there has been a click somewheres that isn't a clown (because the clown would've told it that the hit was good) and we can decrement a life

I hope that's not too confusing. I've slapped together a [GM:S example for you to look at (it works! although it's kind of ugly and there's no sound or polish and losing all your lives or killing all the clowns doesn't mean anything)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21079225/ClownE/clownExample.zip.zip)

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you so much for this, exactly what I was looking for, works like a charm and revealed a whole extra level of thinking for me to boot! I'll admit I was a little confused but that was through lack of knowledge (around using variables in GM, I've only done this one tutorial) but a little digging cleared that right up.

Comment: If you are having any trouble understanding the GML I could try to look up the equivalent drag and drop. Not sure what you use, but I mostly use GML. I tried making most of this with D&D to be more accessible though

Comment: It was, thanks Jeff, just required me to increase my understanding a little. I had an idea about how to send the variable update with D&D this morning so I'll put that to the test tonight. The main issue with GML was just a lack of access to it... I'm assuming there's a way to do it all in code but the only way i could find to add your code snippet was by using the D&D code function, or is that all I need to do? Thanks again :)

Comment: @CLockeWork: To add GML, you have to go through D&D (either the Execute Code command or the Execute Script command)

Comment: I should have waited to go through the other tutorials before I asked that. Thanks Jeff, I've started doing all my work with code instead of D&D, it's much tidier.